# Conseguir o valor máximo de uma soma SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu preciso saber o maior valor de uma soma, como fazer ?

```
select cod_prod,sum (quantidade) as quantidade from produtos 
group by cod_prod
```

Comment: Acho que você pode ordenar por ordem decrescente e utilizar a clausula Top para obter apenas o primeiro (maior) resultado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você poderia fazer dessa maneira, apenas adicionando o "*TOP*" e o "*ORDER BY*"

```
SELECT TOP 1 cod_prod, sum (quantidade) as quantidade
FROM produtos 
GROUP BY cod_prod 
ORDER BY quantidade DESC
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!